# Node express command not found

Tags: node.js, express

i have used `npm install -g express`.
then used `npm install -g express-generator`

but when after install , i type express-V still told me :`-bash: express: command not found`.

please help me how to figure out this problem

Comment: You Say "Bash" that mean that you are running under linux or something similar. If a command could not be found from the system, it is not in in the Path environment variable. Check your NPM installation regarding environment variables. You need to include the global modules folder of npm in your Path.

Comment: Ideally, you should not be installing express globally, ie with `-g`. If you are just looking to play around with the framework, a better learning experience would involve not using the generator but reading the docs and setting everything up from scratch. Want some reference, **Shameless plug**, https://github.com/swarajgiri/express-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You Say "Bash" that mean that you are running under linux or something similar. If a command could not be found from the system, it is not in in the Path environment variable. Check your NPM installation regarding environment variables. You need to include the global modules folder of npm in your Path.

Thanks for your answer.i reset the path environment and then it has been figured out.